# Will smoked-then-fried foods impart smoke flavor to cooking oil?

Tags: chicken, frying, smoking, chicken-wings

I am preparing for a chicken wing cooking competition later this month. One way I've been making wings lately is starting with a ride in the smoker to par cook and add a hint of smokey goodness (think apple wood smoked roasted garlic butter wings).

During the competition I plan to offer some smoked wings as well as some non-smoked wings.

I am worried my smoked wings will leech so much smoke flavor into my oil that I will have to either fry them all *after* I cook the non-smoked wings or use multiple fryers and designate one for each style.

I haven't had a chance to test this theory yet. Am I over thinking it or will this be a problem?

Comment: You realize that we are all hoping for an authoritative answer from you after your competition? Good luck! ^_^

Comment: The next test batch should offer some evidence to help answer this question. Hopefully this weekend! Thank you :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The smoke flavour will definitely impart into the oil and you will have to cook the wings separately to achieve the desired flavour difference. 
Cheers Dean